# Creating a Common AppBar in metro application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

in my current C# WinRT MvvmLight application, I'm experiencing a lot of duplication code with my AppBar. Besides the login page, all my pages support the same AppBar. Is there any way to abstract the xaml code, as well as the xaml.cs code (e.g., UI element modifications upon click)

Any xaml page besides the login page:

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
  <AppBar>
     <!-- content here -->
  </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
<Page.BottomAppBar>
  <AppBar>
     <!-- content here -->
  </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Any xaml.cs page besides the login page:

```
private void UserLogout_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) {
     //First we need to find out how big our window is, so we can center to it.
     CoreWindow currentWindow = Window.Current.CoreWindow;

     //Set our background rectangle to fill the entire window
     rectBackgroundHide.Height = currentWindow.Bounds.Height;
     rectBackgroundHide.Width = currentWindow.Bounds.Width;
     rectBackgroundHide.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);

     //Make sure the background is visible
     rectBackgroundHide.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;

     //Now we figure out where the center of the screen is, and we 
     //move the popup to that location.
     popupLogout.HorizontalOffset = (currentWindow.Bounds.Width / 2) - (400 / 2);
     popupLogout.VerticalOffset = (currentWindow.Bounds.Height / 2) - (150 / 2);
     popupLogout.IsOpen = true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your `AppBar` add to Resources with some key, for example in `Page.Resources`:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <AppBar x:Key="MyFavoriteAppBar" x:Shared="False" ... />
</Page.Resources>
```

And in other sources use like this:

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyFavoriteAppBar}" />
</Page.TopAppBar>

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyFavoriteAppBar}" />
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

For WPF it's worked perfectly when you setting [`x:Shared="False"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970778(v=vs.100).aspx) for your Resource, but in WinRT does not have this same feature, it does not support this attribute.

Therefore, need to look for alternatives, as one of the options can be found [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21459984/binding-the-content-property-of-a-contentcontrol-in-winrt).

Example:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Name="MyFavoriteAppBar" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <AppBar ... />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Page.TopAppBar>
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MyFavoriteAppBar}" />
    </Page.TopAppBar>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MyFavoriteAppBar}" />
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Grid>
```

In order `Click` event to successfully work in your case, you need to determine [`EventSetter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventsetter.aspx) in Style, or use the Command instead.

Comment: @theStig: My answer to help you?